# Сравнительный оборот

Tags: пунктуация

Все время путаюсь в этих оборотах с "как". Не могу понять, где он употребляется в значении "в качестве", а где в значении "подобно". Не говоря уже о примыкании к сказуемому. Вот, например, здесь.

Создаваемый механизм помещается на месяцы в воображение конструктора, как деталь на металлорежущем станке, конструктор «входит в образ» и живет с ним, отесывая несовершенства.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мне кажется. что предложение надо исправить: "Создаваемый механизм помещается на месяцы в воображение конструктора, как деталь (=помещается) на металлорежущий станок, конструктор «входит в образ» и живет с ним, отесывая несовершенства.

ПОЯСНЕНИЕ

1) Как решаются такие задачи? Вот удобная методика. Если есть повтор (механизм и деталь), то это тождество или сравнение. В нашем случае мы имеем СРАВНЕНИЕ (механизм КАК деталь). Тогда обособление следует считать основной формой, оборот можно назвать "попутным сравнением".

Сравнительный оборот не обособляется только при тесной связи со сказуемым (оно без оборота лексически полностью не выражено) или когда в нераспространенном предложении оборот является обстоятельством и входит в основное сообщение (это уже не попутное сравнение).

2) В приведенном предложении мы имеем даже не сравнительный оборот, а неполное сравнительное предложение с пропущенным сказуемым, которое обязательно обособляется.

Comment: Все равно еще не очень понимаю... Вот еще два примера: Крюк от рыболовного до 1000-тонного грузоподъемного неисчерпаем, как атом. С конструктором следует считаться как с магнатом невидимого капитала, уникального опыта и творческих способностей. Как здесь нужно?

Comment: (1)Крюк от рыболовного до 1000-тонного грузоподъемного неисчерпаем как атом. Если убрать "как атом", то смысл предложения непонятен. Поэтому "неисчерпаем как атом" - это "совершенно неисчерпаем", обстоятельство степени. (Фактически на правах устойчивого оборота). (2) С конструктором следует считаться как с магнатом невидимого капитала, уникального опыта и творческих способностей.  Здесь уже значение "в качестве, считая", тесная связь со сказуемым, то есть "считаться как с магнатом - это  "считать магнатом", а это уже составное именное сказуемое.

Comment: Спасибо. Попытаюсь разобраться.

Comment: Магнат капитала... Да ещё невидимого... Неудивительно, Алёнка, что не понимаете Кто это вам так пишет?!

Я бы не ставил в последнем случае запятую. Там "в качестве". А "неисчерпаем, как атом" – нужна, чистое сравнение.

Comment: А-а!!! Так нужна или нет? Я, если честно, тоже сначала склонялась к запятой... "Крюк неисчерпаем" - это так может написать только конструктор, это образно говоря. Но здесь это уже данность. А вот "неисчерпаем как атом" - это мне кажется не устойчивое сочетание... Хотя не уверена.

Comment: "Неисчерпаем, как атом" - это явный сравнительный оборот, где "как" в значении "подобно". Устойчивости оборота я здесь не вижу. Это ведь не "голодный как волк"

Comment: Нужна, нужна. Выражение слямзили у Ленина, но вряд ли оно стало с тех пор устойчивым сочетанием. "*Электрон так же неисчерпаем, как и атом*". Посмотрите первоисточник.

Comment: "Электрон так же неисчерпаем, как и атом". Кто бы спорил, классическое обособление (ТАК, КАК И). Крюк неисчерпаем так же, как атом. Тоже правильно. Крюк, как атом,  неисчерпаем.  И это правильно. А крюк неисчерпАем, как Атом - это уже сомнительно, здесь уже возможно авторское решение. Делаем два ударения? А мне кажется, что лучше с одним: крюк неисчерпаем как Атом. Но формальная орфография возражает, она еще не считает выражение "достаточно" устойчивым. Что ж, МОЖНО ПОСТАВИТЬ ЗАПЯТУЮ, чтобы все были довольны. Там своя методика: найти что-нибудь похожее и оформить примерно так же.